# How to align grob with ggplot using ggplotGrob and annotation_custom?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a grob from a ggplot using `ggplotGrob` and then adding it as a background layer in a complex ggplot construction using `annotation_custom` since the performance is much improved in a `facet_wrap` plot with a large dataset. However I am unable to align the underlying grob correctly with the ggplot.

This simple example shows the issue I am trying to solve.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "red")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(p)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplotGrob background layer]

I want the plot with red points to be perfectly underneath the plot with black points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd probably want to grab just the panel without axis, margins etc. before adding it as a custom annotation then. In example below, I made the red points larger so you can see that they overlap.

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "red", size = 3)

grab_panel <- function(p) {
  gt <- ggplotGrob(p)
  layout <- gt$layout
  is_panel <- which(layout$name == "panel")[[1]]
  i <- layout$t[is_panel]
  j <- layout$l[is_panel]
  gt[i,j]
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  annotation_custom(grob = grab_panel(p)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick and I learned a bit about the pieces to a ggplot.